# How to clear values from textbox using Selenium in VBA

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

When I tried to clear values from textbox or combobox using `.Clear` an error shows like

````
Selenium error, element not interactable. Session info: chrome= 76.0.3809.87  Driver info: chromedriver =76.0.3809.25
```Dim bot As New WebDriver
```bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='textbox/combobox_ID']").Clear
````

I expected the output is to clear already existing values from `textbox/combobox`.

Comment: Could you share the code that caused the error so the community can try to reproduce the error? What solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: to clear data i used the code is  bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='Initials_SWE02739_14']").Clear

Answer (score 0):

Using, Xpath which you already used in your VBA code, you would be able to clear the search box, if it's not getting cleared then after loading the website code, kindly use a wait time and then code for clear.
For ex:

```
Dim bot As New WebDriver
with bot
 .wait 3000
 .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='textbox/combobox_ID']").Clear
 new input codes
End With
```

Above logic might work.